# Accessing blog posts by a users friends

Tags: php, blogs

I am using the EasySocial and EasyBlog extensions on my current project. I have successfully customized the majority of the codes myself, but I am having trouble with my current assignment.

I need to create a code for a module that will display ONLY the blog posts written by a users friends. I believe I need to start it something like:

```
$friends = Foundry::model('friends')->getFriends( $userId );
```

Then I was thinking that I need to do a mysqli search query in order to find the blogs written by each of the users friends. Would it go something like this?:

```
$blogsearch = mysqli_query ($con, "SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE uid = '" . Foundry::user()->id . "' AND data LIKE '%MINIARTS%'");

For each ($friends), "SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE blogposts"

echo rand()
```

I know this is not the best start but I just desperately need some direction.

Comment: You could use something like: select * from tablename where uid IN (implode(','$friends));

Answer (score 0):

You can use Blog app from app directory which will show Blog posts by a user from his profile use this free app from here [EasyBlog Application](http://stackideas.com/apps/item/5-blog)